# Mouse not usable on specific USB port (Windows and Linux)

Tags: linux, windows, usb, mouse, wireless-mouse

*This is an operating system-agnostic issue, but I have logs from Ubuntu 14.10.*

I have this [Perixx PERIMICE-710R USB wireless mouse](http://amzn.com/B006UIFTTS):

[image: Perixx Perimice-710R]

It is not usable through a specific USB port on a [Lenovo Y510p laptop](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/y-series/y510p/):

[image: Lenovo Y510p]

The mouse works on the two USB ports on the other side of this laptop.

Here is why Linux says that mouse cannot be used (from `/var/log/syslog`):

```
Feb 12 19:53:10 Deltique kernel: [  165.657532] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
Feb 12 19:53:10 Deltique kernel: [  165.825757] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Feb 12 19:53:10 Deltique kernel: [  165.929804] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Setup ERROR: setup context command for slot 15.
Feb 12 19:53:10 Deltique kernel: [  165.929816] usb 3-2: hub failed to enable device, error -22
Feb 12 19:53:10 Deltique kernel: [  166.041952] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
Feb 12 19:53:10 Deltique kernel: [  166.210149] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Feb 12 19:53:10 Deltique kernel: [  166.314214] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Setup ERROR: setup context command for slot 16.
Feb 12 19:53:10 Deltique kernel: [  166.314227] usb 3-2: hub failed to enable device, error -22
Feb 12 19:53:10 Deltique kernel: [  166.426300] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
Feb 12 19:53:10 Deltique kernel: [  166.426598] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Feb 12 19:53:11 Deltique kernel: [  166.630703] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Feb 12 19:53:11 Deltique kernel: [  166.834618] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 17, error -71
Feb 12 19:53:11 Deltique kernel: [  166.946822] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
Feb 12 19:53:11 Deltique kernel: [  166.947120] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Feb 12 19:53:11 Deltique kernel: [  167.151232] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Feb 12 19:53:11 Deltique kernel: [  167.355159] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 18, error -71
Feb 12 19:53:11 Deltique kernel: [  167.355257] usb usb3-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

After setting the `modprobe` setting `options usbcore old_scheme_first=y` as suggested by [this email](http://www.spinics.net/lists/usb/msg02644.html), this line showed:

```
Feb 12 20:09:10 Deltique kernel: [  470.466364] usb 3-2: new low-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
```

After five seconds, presumably `usbcore` tried to fall back to its “new scheme” and the same errors above were logged again.

Here is Linux successfully recognizing the USB device on a different USB port on the same computer:

```
Feb 12 20:03:49 Deltique kernel: [  148.210664] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
Feb 12 20:03:49 Deltique kernel: [  148.341256] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=062a, idProduct=4101
Feb 12 20:03:49 Deltique kernel: [  148.341264] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Feb 12 20:03:49 Deltique kernel: [  148.341268] usb 3-4: Product: 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
Feb 12 20:03:49 Deltique kernel: [  148.341272] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: MOSART Semi.
Feb 12 20:03:49 Deltique kernel: [  148.341556] usb 3-4: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
Feb 12 20:03:49 Deltique kernel: [  148.343354] input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/0003:062A:4101.0007/input/input19
Feb 12 20:03:49 Deltique kernel: [  148.343614] hid-generic 0003:062A:4101.0007: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
Feb 12 20:03:49 Deltique kernel: [  148.346032] input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.1/0003:062A:4101.0008/input/input20
Feb 12 20:03:49 Deltique kernel: [  148.346454] hid-generic 0003:062A:4101.0008: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1
Feb 12 20:03:49 Deltique mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 26: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4"
Feb 12 20:03:49 Deltique mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 26 was not an MTP device
```

I am able to mount USB mass storage devices on the right USB port, so why can’t I use a mouse on this port?

Comment: What are the exact model of this Lenovo laptop and mouse?

Comment: @harrymc Click on the images to find out.  In the case of link rotting, the laptop is a [Lenovo Y510p](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/y-series/y510p/), and the mouse is a [Perixx PERIMICE-710R](http://amzn.com/B006UIFTTS).

Comment: Are you using the [latest Lenovo drivers](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-y-series-laptops/ideapad-y510p-notebook)? Or does Windows Update find any driver updates in the optional section?

Comment: @harrymc The latest Lenovo drivers for that laptop are in use on Windows, and neither Windows Update nor Jockey (on Ubuntu) has additional driver updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They say violence never solved anything, but after prying open my laptop and punching the USB port senseless while shouting, "Work, you stupid thing!", this miracle happened:

```
Mar  8 20:48:56 Deltique kernel: [  712.368555] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 62 using xhci_hcd
Mar  8 20:48:56 Deltique kernel: [  712.498967] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=062a, idProduct=4101
Mar  8 20:48:56 Deltique kernel: [  712.498972] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Mar  8 20:48:56 Deltique kernel: [  712.498974] usb 3-2: Product: 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
Mar  8 20:48:56 Deltique kernel: [  712.498976] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: MOSART Semi.
Mar  8 20:48:56 Deltique kernel: [  712.499161] usb 3-2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
Mar  8 20:48:56 Deltique kernel: [  712.500538] input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:062A:4101.000F/input/input25
Mar  8 20:48:56 Deltique kernel: [  712.500728] hid-generic 0003:062A:4101.000F: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
Mar  8 20:48:56 Deltique kernel: [  712.502617] input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:062A:4101.0010/input/input26
Mar  8 20:48:56 Deltique kernel: [  712.502908] hid-generic 0003:062A:4101.0010: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
Mar  8 20:48:56 Deltique mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 62: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2"
Mar  8 20:48:56 Deltique mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 62 was not an MTP device
```

In all seriousness, the reason the mouse was not usable was a hardware problem with the USB port.  The cause is unknown, but I probably tripped over a USB device that was connected to that port in the past.

[image: All good.]

Answer (score 2):

Your plugging your mouse into USB 3.0 Port,

```
Feb 12 19:53:11 Deltique kernel: [  167.355257] usb usb3-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Your external drives have 3.0 USB support feature so it's working.. 
If your mouse need to work with USB 3 Port you need to install the driver for USB 3.

Comment: No some USB port only Supports 3.o

Answer (score 1):

Similar type of bugs I also used to get, This might be because you are trying to connect to a High speed USB port by a low speed device.

Put your USB port informations from the system information.

`usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd`

Go through this links for further details

http://www.linux-usb.org/FAQ.html#ts6

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1731989

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-source-2.6.15/+bug/54273

Answer (score 1):

The trouble might be because Windows 8.1 uses a generic driver for the USB 3 port.
Try to find a better driver on the manufacturer's website.

You can find out the make and driver details in the Device Manager under Universal Serial Bus controllers.
If this is for example an Intel USB hub, use the [Intel Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect)
to automatically identify and find drivers for all Intel hardware on the computer.

If a non-generic driver does not help, the problem is probably due to poor hardware implementation
of the USB 3 port by Lenovo.

A simple google search for [Lenovo Y510p "usb 3"](https://www.google.fr/search?num=30&safe=off&q=Lenovo%20Y510p%20%22usb%203%22&oq=Lenovo%20Y510p%20%22usb%203%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i22i30l6.2660.6501.0.9154.7.7.0.0.0.0.102.505.6j1.7.0.msedr...0...1c.1.62.serp..0.7.501.ZNTVKRXxlUU) has this in the first page of results:

[USB 3.0 port does not work with Kingston 32 GB usb 3.0 stick](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/USB-3-0-problem-on-Y510p-laptop-Windows-7-Ultimate/td-p/1354019)
[Y510p Usb 3.0 drop out](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/y510p-usb-3-0-drop-out.762379/)
[Lenovo IdeaPad Y510P USB 3.0 HDD connected to USB 3.0 port won't power off after unmounting](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1401980)
[Intensity Shuttle USB 3.0 fix for Win 8 64](http://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=12185)

These articles imply that some devices have problems when plugged-in to this port,
problems that they do not experience when connected to a USB 2 port,
as is exactly your case.

The source of the problem can either be hardware or driver.
While the driver can be replaced, one cannot do that with the hardware.

Comment: Upon physical inspection of the USB ports, I found that the ones on the left are blue, for USB 3.0, I presume.  The one on the right is yellow, probably for USB 2.0.  Perhaps the hardware believes that the right port is USB 3.0 when it is in fact USB 2.0?

Comment: In that case, Lenovo got their wires crossed. However, the ports can be visually identified: USB 3 has 5 leads and USB 2 has 4. See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/647947/8672) and [this one](http://superuser.com/a/756671/8672). It is also possible that Lenovo connected the right ports to the wrong hub (one can check if some USB3 device works at the right speed on the right port).