# How to identify USB 3 port on my laptop

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-3, usb-c

I have a laptop thinkpad L450. Having `3 USB` port which are identical with `SS` symbols and color `(black)`.
But I have want to know if they are actually USB 3 or its just a normal USB?

Here is the image of my `Device Manager`
As shown in the pictuere its showingf only one `USB 3.0` on right, but how are they showing same symbols.

As per [link here](https://superuser.com/a/640950/593603) `SS` are `USB 3`

[image]

Comment: The easiest way I know of is to plug in a device that is explicitly a USB3 device. If the port does not support USB3 speeds, you will get a message saying that the device could operate faster if...

Comment: Even though the linked question is for Windows 7, most of the info there applies to Windows 10 as well. This _could_ be considered a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - They are in fact multiple duplicates.  Given this question received a question that indicates the same information as an answer to the duplicate I have no hesitation to close it as a duplicate

Comment: No Problem in closing, but why my ports are in black color.

Comment: @Mongrel - The color of the plastic is not actually relevant; it's common to use it as an indicator, but it's not mandatory. If your laptop's manufacturer was trying to cut cost, they may have chosen to not use multiple colors of plastic for the USB ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbols *ought* to indicate the type of port. See this image:

[image: USB symbols]

If it has the `SS` it's a USB 3 port **(often blue)**
If it only has the hub (base USB logo) it's a USB2 port
If it has the lightning symbol it's a USB + charging (should be on when the device is powered off/slumbering) **(often yellow)**
If It has the letters `PD` it's a Power Delivery USB 3 port which may be able to supply more power.

Be aware that there may be more USB hubs in you device manager, especially on laptops. Webcams, Keyboards and touchpads, as well as biometric sensors and keycard readers, and SD card readers are also USB, and may be connected to an internal USB2 hub without any external ports...

Comment: But all my USB port are having `ss` & all are black, because of this I have raised this question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.